# array_keys vs array_flip benchmark request

Tags: php

Sorry for a silly quastion, more like a request..
Been using `array_keys` but suddenly swapped it with `array_flip` and saw no difference, can somebody benchmark it? ::

Comment: what failed when you tried to benchmark it?

Comment: nothing, both functions are quick, just wondering which one to use.. need a signle choice :o

Comment: array_flip has also the old keys as value, so is double the size, has double the work. But I didn't benchmark it. If you bother benchmark it!!

Comment: oh thats true, only tried with numeric array, didnt think of random keys

Comment: so the way to access the keys is different also.

Comment: for 100000 radnom keys and values of 111 characters length, out of avarage time from 100 tries of array_flip, it gave 0.0098383688926697 ms. and array_keys 0.0012835931777954 ms, but then.. what does array_keys do when you loop it..

Comment: and 1 try without looping for a big array 0.0062 for array_keys and 0.0252 for array_flip..

Comment: Do you have an array now or ever with 100,000 keys of 111 character lengths? Do you have any where near that volume? If not then test with a realistic value like 100 keys and when you see the difference is so tiny, you will choose the *correct* one for the task at hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions perform different tasks. Do you need keys exchanged with their associated values? Or do you just need all keys? Use whichever one you need to achieve the task.

There are pretty much always many routes to take that achieve the same outcome, but (eg) perhaps it doesn't matter if the array order is changed or not, then don't use the one which flips as it'll (theoretically/speculatively) take longer and it's not the right tool for the task.

If you have huge sets of data and/or many iterations of it, and as such these things are relevant to you, then you should have benchmark systems setup to test this scenario and likely others. If not then like most applications, such considerations are micro-optimisation and choice of the tool/function should be one which fits the task - and suits your code base or framework, coding style, etc.

Choosing the one which suits the task also makes *intent* more clear. So eg if you don't need to flip the array, even if that function is marginally faster, use the one you actually need otherwise a future refactor might leave someone scratching their head a little at your choice of using `array_flip()`.

---

[array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

> array_flip — Exchanges all keys with their associated values in an
>   array

```
$input = array("oranges", "apples", "pears");
$flipped = array_flip($input);

Array
(
    [oranges] => 0
    [apples] => 1
    [pears] => 2
)
```

[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

> array_keys — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

Do you need them flipped? Or do you just need the keys? If not need flipped then use the latter, else use the former.

Array flip also states

> If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its value, and all others will be lost.

Maybe this is a problem to you? Maybe it doesn't matter?